# How to get the value of a property in a litteral object within an auto-executable method

Tags: javascript, oop

I want to do this:

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    __test__: (function() {alert(this.name)})()
}
```

but this.name is undefined. How to have its value then ?

Update: to make more sense, I rather want to do this ie auto-inialisation:

```
var person = {
    name: "",
    __test__: (function() {name = "john"})()
}`
```

'John' can come in real world from a mockup object, a database whatever, my point is I want to do this in a SELF-CONTAINED way not call **test** from an external object.

Comment: It's defined for me. What setup are you using?

Comment: What is the meaning of the code???

Comment: @Blender I tested again in Dashcode / iPhone Simulator it is undefined for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this using an Object literal. `this` is referring to `person` *after* the literal is evaluated, during evaluation `this` refers to the parent scope. You could wrap the object construction in a function to be sure `this` refers to the current scope (i.e. the scope of the function). Something like:

```
var person = function(){
    this.name = 'John';
    this.__test__ = (function(){alert(this.name);}());
    return this;
}();
```

Or using variables within the function scope:

```
var person = function(){
    var _name = 'John'
        ,_test = (function(){alert(_name);}());
    return { name: _name, __test__: _test };
}();
```

Or wrap things in a more generic factory function:

```
function objFactory(obj){
    var nwObj = {};
    for (var l in obj){
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(l)){
            if (obj[l] instanceof Function && /^auto_/i.test(l)){
             nwObj[l.replace(/^auto_/i,'')] = obj[l].call(nwObj);
            }
            else {
             nwObj[l] = obj[l];
            }
        }
    }
   return nwObj;
}
//=> usage
var person = objFactory(
               { name: '', 
                 auto_name: function(){
                             this.name='John'; 
                             return this.name;
                            }
                }
             );
 alert(person.name); //=> John
```

And finally (not everyone will agree to this) you could create a load handler in `Object.prototype`:

```
Object.prototype.load = function(){
    for (var l in this){
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(l) 
            && this[l] instanceof Function 
            && /^auto_/i.test(l)) {
          this[l].call(this);
          delete this[l];
        }
    }
    return this;
}
//=> usage
var person = {
               name: '', 
               auto_name: function(){this.name='John';}
             }.load();
alert(person.name); //=> John
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll think about it. Nevertheless literal object is light syntax and less verbose than full blown class with constructor that's why I'd like to be able to do that way. And I wouldn't understand why a litteral object would behave differently from an object constructed with a function.

Comment: @user310291: in this case it's not a full blown constructor (javascript doesn't know classes by the way), but an Immediately Invoked (anonymous) Function. I've added an example which more clearly demonstrates the scoping.

Comment: @user310291: glad I could help. Just for fun: I added a more generic factory function doing the same

Answer (score 1):

The scope of the code with *auto-executable function* is the `window`(I guess it's becuase it is who called the function and not `person`).

So, I think it can not be done(this way).

see this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BDxQh/)

**Why won't use this instead:**

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    __test__: function() {alert(this.name)}
}
person.__test__();
```

Comment: I want to do this in a SELF-CONTAINED way not call test from an external object.

Comment: @user310291. why does Kooilnc answer is not enough for this need?

Comment: yes Kooilnc could do it it's just I wish to be able to use literal object. Sounds stupid to have to change syntax just because of this.

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
var person = {
    name: "John",
    __test__: function() { alert(this.name) }
};
person.test();
```

This assigns an anonymous function to *person.test* which can be executed with *person.test()*. In your original code, you had a self executing function which means *person.test* is assigned the result of the anonymous function which is undefined (since it did not return anything.

As for why it alerts undefined, google how JavaScript closures and anonymous functions work. Basically, *this* loses its context in self executing anonymous functions.

Comment: it doesn't matter that person.__test__ is assigned a value since the return value doesn't matter. I don't want to call outside the object as I want to do this in a SELF-CONTAINED way not call test from an external object.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot possibly do that as you are trying to access the object before it has been constructed. Secondly, you are creating an anonymous function and executing withThat is the value will be evaluated without context to the object and then stored with the appropriate key.

```
var func = function() {return this;}; 
// when invoked as such
func();
// will return global namespace (or window in a browser).

var obj = {"func": func};

obj.func(); 
// now calling func on obj so this is now obj and returns obj
```

Maybe you could acheive what you want with a constructor:

```
function MyObject() {

    this.name = "John";
    this.__test_func__ = function() {alert(this.name);};
    this.__test__ = this.__test_func__();

    // or you could try passing in your object explicitly
    this.__test__ = (function(pseudo_this){alert(pseudo_this.name);})(this);
}

var obj = new MyObject();
```

One other thing, alert doesn't have a return value (it returns undefined). I assume you knew that, and were just trying to examine the state of the object midway through construction. You'll have need to use a constructor rather than literal if you want to do anything more complicated than just specifying the contents of an object.

Comment: OK thanks for all explanation - unfortunately can only mark one good answer - seems everybody tells I cannot do it with literal object but use constructor.